# Убрать пустое пространство c области графика Time Series с разрывами

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

В данных есть отсутствующие значения, хочу построить график без них, чтобы даты в эти периоды не отображались.
пример графика с разрывом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то, что хотелось бы получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подготовка данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['GOOG']=np.where(
    (df['date']>pd.to_datetime('01.10.2018', dayfirst=True))&(df['date']<pd.to_datetime('01.04.2019',dayfirst=True)),
    np.nan, 
    df['GOOG'])
```

Убираю даты с отсутствующими значениями:

```
df2=df.dropna()

fig2 = px.line(df2, x='date', y="GOOG")
```

В итоге получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал конвертацию даты в строковый тип данных - не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, должен ли быть график соединен, потому что в условиях написано без отсутствующих значений.

Первый блок видимо оставляем как у вас:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['GOOG']=np.where(
    (df['date']>pd.to_datetime('01.10.2018', dayfirst=True))&(df['date']<pd.to_datetime('01.04.2019',dayfirst=True)),
    np.nan, 
    df['GOOG'])
```

Далее делаем дату строковым индексом и строим плот

```
df.index = df.date.astype(str)
df.dropna()['GOOG'].plot(rot=60)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то так.

**UPD**

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))

df2=df.dropna()

fig2 = px.line(df2, x='date', y="GOOG")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это то что нужно, но к сожалению в библиотеке plolty... ваш вариант не работает в plotly, по всей видимости это какая-то особенность работы библиотеки, которую я не понимаю как обойти

Comment: добавил изменения @Alexandr

Comment: Да, работает. По всей видимости plotly такой символ не распознает (/). Также можно конвертнуть с помощью df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

Answer (score 1):

На английском SO есть ещё [такой рецепт](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346100/plotly-how-to-style-a-plotly-figure-so-that-it-doesnt-display-gaps-for-missing), основанный на указании `rangebreaks`:

```
dt_all = pd.date_range(start=df['date'].iloc[0],end=df['date'].iloc[-1])
dt_obs = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])]

# define dates with missing values
dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist() if not d in dt_obs]

# hide dates with no values
fig2.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=dt_breaks)])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]